# Clone repo from github to xcode issues

Tags: xcode, github, clone, github-for-mac

I have tried following a few tutorials on cloning a github repo and opening it up on xcode. I first connected my github account to xcode and then I selected a project to clone. I then placed it into my folder where all my projects are stored. Then I went to xcode to open an existing project but when I try to select the project I cloned I get this message:

```
Could not open file. (/Users/username/Documents/Dev/Linked-Lists)
```

I am not sure what the issue is. Here is the url I am trying to clone: https://github.com/wwolfgang11/Linked-Lists

From what I found online, once I clone an existing repository and save it either my desktop or some folder, then Xcode should automatically open up the project. In my case that does not happen and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SmileyCreations identified the problem (the repo doesn't have an Xcode project), so here's how to solve it:

1) Create a new "macOS" project and set it to be a command line tool:
[image: 1 create new project]
2) Choose the C++ language.
[image: 2 choose the C++ language]
3) Drag in the .cpp and .h files from the repo:
[image: 3 drag in source files]

Comment: also, on line 194 of DoubleLinkedList.h you'll need to add "`noexcept`" (as in "`DoubleLinkedList<T>::~DoubleLinkedList() noexcept`") and I changed the template code on line 207 of that file from `SingleLinkedList` to `DoubleLinkedList`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the folder is not an Xcode project. Xcode project files are folders(bundles) and Xcode will think that the folder is a project and fail to open it. And the repository doesn't contain any `.xcodeproj` files.

Comment: I see, do you know how I could fix this. I go back and forth from different machines to work on projects.

Comment: First upload the project folder to GitHub (include the .xcodeproj file). Now you can commit as usual. And do not forget to commit when you add a file or change something in the project. You can use `git pull` to pull changes. Also push and pull when you switch machines.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked how you can do it here is how you can do it.
Run `git commit` and `git push` when you do the following things:
 1. Change machines 
 2. Edit the project 
 3. Add, edit or delete files. 
Run `git pull` when you do the following things:
 1. When you start to work on a another machine.

Comment: What do you mean change machines?

Comment: okay could you provide an example like you did here for when I want to open a github project given a url on xcode and what to do from there?

Comment: First you should have an `.xcodeproj` file as the project file. It should me located in a folder that is the name of your project. Now add the folder that the .xcodeproj file is in to the repository. Here is an example repository. https://github.com/smileycreations15/Example-repository-1. If you need help ask in the comments.

Comment: Do I just create a new one. My apologies that I am not understanding but I have a number of Github projects that have been created on a Windows machine using microsoft visual c++. So some of them will not have a .xcodeproj

Comment: No, you don't need to create a new one. If you can, create a folder containing all the projects (any project file). Then upload it into a repository that you want. You can use the instructions that is in this answer after you uploaded every project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187074/discussion-between-smileycreations15-and-snorrlaxxx).

Answer (score 0):

you have to open ios folder which is inside you application then it will work.

example:- suppose you project name is myApp

then open xcode > file > open > myApp > ios